# Do CSS grid boxes expand to fit dynamically placed content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm new to CSS grid and am having some difficulties. I'm appending `divs` to a CSS grid box (a `div`) dynamically after page load but the the grid box is not expanding to reflect them (specifically I'm arranging the `divs` in a circle).  The appended `divs` are positioned absolutely with respect to the grid box.  Instead, it seems that they are floating outside of it.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?  And if so, what is the error of my ways?

Here's a CodePen I wrote of what I'm trying to do that should illustrate the problem I'm having: https://codepen.io/Cerulean3/pen/yEpOGN. In the CodePen the red box on the left hand side should expand so that the circle of letters is inside of it.

Here's the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pasapalabra</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div id="bigGrid">
    <div id="letter-display">


    </div>
    <div id="user-interaction">
      <div id="user-output">user output</div>
        <div id="user-input">user input</div>

    </div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the SCSS

```css
body {
  background: royalblue;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  header {
    grid-area: header;
background: #1ab048;
  }

   footer {
    grid-area: footer;
     background: #FCE1E5;
  }
}

#bigGrid {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 10px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:  "letterDisplay . userInteraction" ;

}

#user-interaction {
  background:#BC7A00;
  display: subgrid;
  grid-area:userInteraction;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 10px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "userOutput . userInput ";

}
#user-output {

  grid-area: userOutput;
  background: grey;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
#user-input {
  grid-area: userInput;

}

#letter-display {
  grid-area:letterDisplay;
  position: relative;
  background: #FF0000;
  div {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', sans-serif;

    background: lightblue;
    border: blueviolet 1px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    span {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}
```

and the JavaScript

```js
const log = console.log.bind(null);


function QuestionGenerator() {
    this.data = [
        {
            letter: "a",
            answer: "abducir",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA A. Dicho de una supuesta criatura extraterrestre: Apoderarse de alguien"), ("CON LA A. 2 Dicho de una supuesta criatura extraterrestre: Apoderarse de alguien"), ("CON LA A. 3Dicho de una supuesta criatura extraterrestre: Apoderarse de alguien")]
        },
        {
            letter: "b",
            answer: "bingo",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA B. Juego que ha sacado de quicio a todos los 'Skylabers' en las sesiones de precurso"), ("CON LA B. 2 Juego que ha sacado de quicio a todos los 'Skylabers' en las sesiones de precurso"), ("CON LA B. 3 Juego que ha sacado de quicio a todos los 'Skylabers' en las sesiones de precurso")]
        },
        {
            letter: "c",
            answer: "churumbel",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA C. Niño, crío, bebé"), ("CON LA C. Niño, crío, bebé"), ("CON LA C. Niño, crío, bebé")]
        },
        {
            letter: "d",
            answer: "diarrea",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA D. Anormalidad en la función del aparato digestivo caracterizada por frecuentes evacuaciones y su consistencia líquida"), ("CON LA D. Anormalidad en la función del aparato digestivo caracterizada por frecuentes evacuaciones y su consistencia líquida"), ("CON LA D. Anormalidad en la función del aparato digestivo caracterizada por frecuentes evacuaciones y su consistencia líquida")
            ]
        },
        {
            letter: "e",
            answer: "ectoplasma",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA E. Gelatinoso y se encuentra debajo de la membrana plasmática. Los cazafantasmas medían su radiación"), ("CON LA E. Gelatinoso y se encuentra debajo de la membrana plasmática. Los cazafantasmas medían su radiación"), ("CON LA E. Gelatinoso y se encuentra debajo de la membrana plasmática. Los cazafantasmas medían su radiación")]
        },
        {
            letter: "f",
            answer: "facil",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA F. Que no requiere gran esfuerzo, capacidad o dificultad"), ("CON LA F. Que no requiere gran esfuerzo, capacidad o dificultad"), ("CON LA F. Que no requiere gran esfuerzo, capacidad o dificultad")]
        },
        {
            letter: "g",
            answer: "galaxia",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA G. Conjunto enorme de estrellas, polvo interestelar, gases y partículas"), ("CON LA G. Conjunto enorme de estrellas, polvo interestelar, gases y partículas"), ("CON LA G. Conjunto enorme de estrellas, polvo interestelar, gases y partículas")]
        },
        {
            letter: "h",
            answer: "harakiri",
            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA H. Suicidio ritual japonés por desentrañamiento"), ("CON LA H. Suicidio ritual japonés por desentrañamiento"), ("CON LA H. Suicidio ritual japonés por desentrañamiento")]
        },
        {
            letter: "i",
            answer: "iglesia",
            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA I. Templo cristiano"), ("CON LA I. Templo cristiano"), ("CON LA I. Templo cristiano")]
        },
        {
            letter: "j",
            answer: "jabali",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA J. Variedad salvaje del cerdo que sale en la película 'El Rey León', de nombre Pumba"), ("CON LA J. Variedad salvaje del cerdo que sale en la película 'El Rey León', de nombre Pumba"), ("CON LA J. Variedad salvaje del cerdo que sale en la película 'El Rey León', de nombre Pumba")]
        },
        {
            letter: "k",
            answer: "kamikaze",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA K. Persona que se juega la vida realizando una acción temeraria"), ("CON LA K. Persona que se juega la vida realizando una acción temeraria"), ("CON LA K. Persona que se juega la vida realizando una acción temeraria")]
        },
        {
            letter: "l",
            answer: "licantropo",
            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA L. Hombre lobo"), ("CON LA L. Hombre lobo"), ("CON LA L. Hombre lobo")]
        },
        {
            letter: "m",
            answer: "misantropo",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA M. Persona que huye del trato con otras personas o siente gran aversión hacia ellas"), ("CON LA M. Persona que huye del trato con otras personas o siente gran aversión hacia ellas"), ("CON LA M. Persona que huye del trato con otras personas o siente gran aversión hacia ellas")]
        },
        {
            letter: "n",
            answer: "necedad",
            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA N. Demostración de poca inteligencia"), ("CON LA N. Demostración de poca inteligencia"), ("CON LA N. Demostración de poca inteligencia")]
        },
        {
            letter: "ñ",
            answer: "señal",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CONTIENE LA Ñ. Indicio que permite deducir algo de lo que no se tiene un conocimiento directo."), ("CONTIENE LA Ñ. Indicio que permite deducir algo de lo que no se tiene un conocimiento directo."), ("CONTIENE LA Ñ. Indicio que permite deducir algo de lo que no se tiene un conocimiento directo.")]
        },
        {
            letter: "o",
            answer: "orco",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA O. Humanoide fantástico de apariencia terrible y bestial, piel de color verde creada por el escritor Tolkien"), ("CON LA O. Humanoide fantástico de apariencia terrible y bestial, piel de color verde creada por el escritor Tolkien"), ("CON LA O. Humanoide fantástico de apariencia terrible y bestial, piel de color verde creada por el escritor Tolkien")]
        },
        {
            letter: "p",
            answer: "protoss",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA P. Raza ancestral tecnológicamente avanzada que se caracteriza por sus grandes poderes psíonicos del videojuego StarCraft"), ("CON LA P. Raza ancestral tecnológicamente avanzada que se caracteriza por sus grandes poderes psíonicos del videojuego StarCraft")]
        },
        {
            letter: "q",
            answer: "queso",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA Q. Producto obtenido por la maduración de la cuajada de la leche"), ("CON LA Q. Producto obtenido por la maduración de la cuajada de la leche"), ("CON LA Q. Producto obtenido por la maduración de la cuajada de la leche")]
        },
        {
            letter: "r",
            answer: "raton",
            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA R. Roedor"), ("CON LA R. Roedor"), ("CON LA R. Roedor")]
        },
        {
            letter: "s",
            answer: "stackoverflow",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA S. Comunidad salvadora de todo desarrollador informático"), ("CON LA S. Comunidad salvadora de todo desarrollador informático"), ("CON LA S. Comunidad salvadora de todo desarrollador informático")]
        },
        {
            letter: "t",
            answer: "terminator",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA T. Película del director James Cameron que consolidó a Arnold Schwarzenegger como actor en 1984"), ("CON LA T. Película del director James Cameron que consolidó a Arnold Schwarzenegger como actor en 1984"), ("CON LA T. Película del director James Cameron que consolidó a Arnold Schwarzenegger como actor en 1984")]
        },
        {
            letter: "u",
            answer: "unamuno",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA U. Escritor y filósofo español de la generación del 98 autor del libro 'Niebla' en 1914"), ("CON LA U. Escritor y filósofo español de la generación del 98 autor del libro 'Niebla' en 1914"), ("CON LA U. Escritor y filósofo español de la generación del 98 autor del libro 'Niebla' en 1914")]
        },
        {
            letter: "v",
            answer: "vikingos",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA V. Nombre dado a los miembros de los pueblos nórdicos originarios de Escandinavia, famosos por sus incursiones y pillajes en Europa"), ("CON LA V. Nombre dado a los miembros de los pueblos nórdicos originarios de Escandinavia, famosos por sus incursiones y pillajes en Europa"), ("CON LA V. Nombre dado a los miembros de los pueblos nórdicos originarios de Escandinavia, famosos por sus incursiones y pillajes en Europa")]
        },
        {
            letter: "w",
            answer: "sandwich",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CONTIENE LA W. Emparedado hecho con dos rebanadas de pan entre las cuales se coloca jamón y queso"), ("CONTIENE LA W. Emparedado hecho con dos rebanadas de pan entre las cuales se coloca jamón y queso"), ("CONTIENE LA W. Emparedado hecho con dos rebanadas de pan entre las cuales se coloca jamón y queso")]
        },
        {
            letter: "x",
            answer: "botox",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CONTIENE LA X. Toxina bacteriana utilizada en cirujía estética"), ("CONTIENE LA X. Toxina bacteriana utilizada en cirujía estética"), ("CONTIENE LA X. Toxina bacteriana utilizada en cirujía estética")]
        },
        {
            letter: "y",
            answer: "peyote",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CONTIENE LA Y. Pequeño cáctus conocido por sus alcaloides psicoactivos utilizado de forma ritual y medicinal por indígenas americanos"), ("CONTIENE LA Y. Pequeño cáctus conocido por sus alcaloides psicoactivos utilizado de forma ritual y medicinal por indígenas americanos"), ("CONTIENE LA Y. Pequeño cáctus conocido por sus alcaloides psicoactivos utilizado de forma ritual y medicinal por indígenas americanos")]
        },
        {
            letter: "z",
            answer: "zen",

            status: 0,
            question: [("CON LA Z. Escuela de budismo que busca la experiencia de la sabiduría más allá del discurso racional"), ("CON LA Z. Escuela de budismo que busca la experiencia de la sabiduría más allá del discurso racional"), ("CON LA Z. Escuela de budismo que busca la experiencia de la sabiduría más allá del discurso racional")]
        }];

    this.Q_UNANSWERED = 0;
    this.Q_CORRECT = 1;
    this.Q_INCORRECT = 2;
    this.Q_PASAPALABRA = 3;
    this.NO_QUESTIONS = -1;

    this.getCountByQuestionType = function (scoreTypeWanted) {
        return this.data.filter(elem => elem.status === scoreTypeWanted).length;
    };


    this.getNextQuestion = function (questionTypeWanted) {

        const unansweredQuestions = this.data.filter(elem => elem.status === questionTypeWanted);
        if (unansweredQuestions.length == 0) {
            return this.NO_QUESTIONS;
        }

        const nextQuestionData = unansweredQuestions.shift();

        const nextQuestionArray = nextQuestionData.question;
        if (!Array.isArray(nextQuestionArray)) {
            logBad("Error: question data is malformed");
            return null;
        }
        nextQuestionArray.push(nextQuestionArray.shift()); // otra pregunta la próxima vez

        return nextQuestionData;

    };

    this.markQuestion = function (letter, code) {
        const matchingQuestion = this.data.find(elem => elem.letter === letter);
        if (matchingQuestion === undefined) {
            logBad(`markQuestion: Error, matching question not found for letter ${error(letter)}`);
            throw(new Error("Question data is malformed"));
            return;
        }
        matchingQuestion.status = code;

    };

    this.checkAnswer = function (answer, letter) {
        const matchingQuestion = this.data.find(elem => elem.letter === letter);
        if (matchingQuestion === undefined) {
            logBad(`checkAnswer: Error, matching question not found for letter ${error(letter)}`);
            return;
        }

        return answer === matchingQuestion.answer;
    };

    this.reInit = function () {
        this.data.forEach(elem => elem.status = this.Q_UNANSWERED);
    };

    this.getLetters = function () {
        return this.data.map(element => element.letter);
    }
}


const questionGenerator = new QuestionGenerator();
const tablero = {

    letras: questionGenerator.getLetters(),

    layout() {
        const radius = 225;
        const origin = {x: 325, y: 325};

        master = document.getElementById('letter-display');

        const count = this.letras.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            const diva = document.createElement('div');
            const letter = diva.id = this.letras[i];
            master.appendChild(diva);
            diva.innerHTML = "<span>" + letter + "</span>";
            let {x, y} = this.returnCoords(origin.x,origin.y, this.degreesToRad((360 / count) * i), radius);
            let width = window.getComputedStyle(diva).getPropertyValue('width');
            let height = window.getComputedStyle(diva).getPropertyValue('height');
            diva.style.left = x - Number.parseFloat(width) + "px";
            diva.style.top = y - Number.parseFloat(height) + "px";
            log(diva.style.left,diva.style.top);
        }
    },
    degreesToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

    },

    radToDegrees(rad) {
        return radians * (180 / Math.PI);

    },

    returnCoords(originX = 0, originY = 0, radians, radius) {
        let x = originX + (Math.cos(radians) * radius);
        let y = originY + (Math.sin(radians) * radius);
        return ({x, y});
    },

    init() {
        this.layout();
    },

};

window.addEventListener('load', init);

let master;


function init() {
    tablero.init();


}
```

Comment: Show code/material you have tried.

Comment: @Alex -- The original post included a link to a CodePen with all the code.  Perhaps it wasn't evident. I've now included the code directly in the post as well.  I would welcome your help.

Comment: I presume that the CodePen provided was not written by you and was an example of what you wanted. :)

Comment: Ah, OK, no problem, I wasn't clear....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent div is collapsing because its children are positioned absolutely and are thus outside the document flow. The following is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> **absolute**
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created
> for the element in the page layout.

Setting the `height` property and the width of column 1 of the grid based upon the constant values you have for radius and position in the JavaScript will cause the parent div to expand.

Please see code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVJXrW

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if there were a different way that might put the absolutely placed elements back in the flow of the page.  I experimented with `relative` positioning them instead of `absolute` but ended up with a strange spiral pattern instead of a circle.